# How to show only the loaded webpage scrollbar in an xe:dialog

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am trying to do a dialog box that should show a website
So I am using the Dialog control from extension library.

**The following code is triggered from a link**

```
viewScope.url= url
getComponent("dialog1").show();
```

inside the dialog there is an iframe that show the webpage

```
<xe:dialog id="dialog1">
<xp:text escape="false" id="computedField1" tagName="iframe">
    <xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:attr name="src">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.get("url")}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:attr>
        <xp:attr name="width" value="900"></xp:attr>
        <xp:attr name="height" value="600"></xp:attr>
    </xp:this.attrs>
</xp:text>
</xe:dialog>
```

The problem I have is that the dialog show a scrollbar which is not needed as I want the loaded webpage to to show its scrollbar. I don't want two scrollbars

Is there anyway to solve this so that only the loaded webpage show the scrollbar in the dialog and not use the dialogs scrollbar

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it is the DialogBox scroll bar not the scrollbar of the Iframe?(cant see the Image you uploaded) Try disable the Iframe Scrolling:

```
<iframe scrolling="auto|yes|no">
```

Otherwise set the size of the Dialog to fix values.

Comment: I have added scrolling attr to the iframe but it does not help. it is not the iframe,  it is the dialog that show scrollbar
<xp:attr name="scrolling" value="no"></xp:attr>

any suggestion on how to set the dialog values?

Comment: You could try it with Stylesheets .lotusDialog{ max-width:800px !important};

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it might be worth trying. Wrap the iFrame in a div and set the overflow to hidden. See if that helps.

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;"><iframe>...</iframe></div>
```